# Number of maximum apps that can be connected in database

Tags: mongodb, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to know how many android and ios application I can connect with Firebase(mainly for cloud firestore) OR mongodb, and what does it mean by "visible apps" in the firebase.

[image: the part I've marked in red]

the part I marked in red and what does it matter if an app is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question is unlimited I guess, as much as I found out there is no limit to the number of app that can be connected to the firebase and max apps is nothing but app visible on the console.